# Open web view without button, when screen load web view should open

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have applied web view but I am facing a problem I have a rate us button when I click on it another screen open where there is a button "open link" and I click on it a web view open but I do not want to got that inner screen. I want when I click on rate us button it should open web view instead of to open a new screen. I know how to navigate to new screen or URL without tapping a button but I am very confused about this line Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/webview");

```
class rateus extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => Home(),
        "/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("WebView"),
          ),

        ),

      },
    );
  }
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final webView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
//  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: url);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webView.close();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    webView.dispose();
//    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Open Webview"),
      onPressed: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/webview");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you need:

```
import 'dart:async'; // import this library

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // as soon widget is ready you navigate to the webview. 
  Timer.run(() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/webview");
  });
}
```

Comment: Undefined name 'Timer'. I found this error. Btw this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Its perfectly work, but when I came back it show open browser page how can I skip that page while poping it out

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that, can you show the video or screenshot for the same, and your original post is already answered, would you mind accepting the post?